# Failed to Insert Data with zend-form

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a mode named Album as follows:

```
namespace Album\Model;

// Add the following import statements:
use DomainException;
use Zend\Filter\StringTrim;
use Zend\Filter\StripTags;
use Zend\Filter\ToInt;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;
use Zend\Validator\StringLength;

class Album {

    public $id;
    public $artist;
    public $title;
    private $inputFilter;

    public function exchangeArray(array $data) {
        $this->id = !empty($data['_id']) ? $data['_id'] : null;
        $this->artist = !empty($data['artist']) ? $data['artist'] : null;
        $this->title = !empty($data['title']) ? $data['title'] : null;
    }

    public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter) {
        throw new DomainException(sprintf(
                '%s does not allow injection of an alternate input filter', __CLASS__
        ));
    }

    public function getInputFilter() {
        if ($this->inputFilter) {
            return $this->inputFilter;
        }

        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

        $inputFilter->add([
            'name' => 'id',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => [
                ['name' => StripTags::class],
                ['name' => StringTrim::class],
            ],
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => StringLength::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min' => 1,
                        'max' => 100,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);



        $inputFilter->add([
            'name' => 'title',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => [
                ['name' => StripTags::class],
                ['name' => StringTrim::class],
            ],
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => StringLength::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min' => 1,
                        'max' => 100,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);


        $inputFilter->add([
            'name' => 'artist',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => [
                ['name' => StripTags::class],
                ['name' => StringTrim::class],
            ],
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => StringLength::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min' => 1,
                        'max' => 100,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;

        return $this->inputFilter;
    }

    public function getArrayCopy() {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'artist' => $this->artist,
            'title' => $this->title,
        ];
    }

}
```

And a form named AlbumForm as follows:

```
namespace Album\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;

class AlbumForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        // We will ignore the name provided to the constructor
        parent::__construct('album');

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'hidden',
        ]);
        $this->add([
            'name' => 'title',
            'type' => 'text',
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Title',
            ],
        ]);
        $this->add([
            'name' => 'artist',
            'type' => 'text',
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Artist',
            ],
        ]);
        $this->add([
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => [
                'value' => 'Go',
                'id'    => 'submitbutton',
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

And a controller named AlbumController in which I have addAction as follows:

```
public function addAction() {

    $form = new AlbumForm();
    $form->get('submit')->setValue('Add');

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if (!$request->isPost()) {
        return ['form' => $form];
    }

    $album = new Album();
    $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
    $form->setData($request->getPost());

    if (!$form->isValid()) {
        return ['form' => $form];
    }

    $album->exchangeArray($form->getData());
    $this->table->saveAlbum($album);
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
}
```

The module.config.php file is as follows and I see no problem with routing:

```
return [
    // The following section is new and should be added to your file:
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'album' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/album[/:action[/:id]]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\AlbumController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],

    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

but, I cannot add a new album to the db. Once, I press fill the form and hit 'Add' in the Add form, nothing is added and I remain in the same page. Does anyone know where I have messed up?

Answer (score 1):

You have an error on the Model Album. It could have the following change:

```
$inputFilter->add([
    'name' => 'id',
    'required' => true,
    'filters' => [
        ['name' => ToInt::class],
    ],
]);
```